# Use AutoIt library inside VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, autoit

I need to manipulate some windows using VBA macro, and I`ve seen AutoIt has a lot of functions to help me.

Then I would like to import or use the AutoIt API (library) inside my VBA macro. Is it possible?

Note: in my project I have to use VBA macro anyway for other questions.